# How to write multiple objects to a single XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am having two classes class1 and class2. I want to write a single xml. For that i am doing below. But i am not getting as expected.

```
var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(class1));
using (XmlWriter write = XmlWriter.Create(stream, sett))
{
   serializer1.Serialize(write, objclass1);
}

var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(class2));
using (XmlWriter write = XmlWriter.Create(stream, sett))
{
   serializer1.Serialize(write, objclass2);
}
```

But i want an output like below. Where **MAIN** is root element defined by me, the class1 and class2 should lie in between **MAIN root element**

```
<MAIN>
 <class1>
  <ele1>1</ele1>
  <ele2>2</ele2>
  <ele3>3</ele3>
 </class1>
 <class2>
  <ele1>1</ele1>
  <ele2>2</ele2>
  <ele3>3</ele3>
 </class2>
</MAIN>
```

Is there any way to get output like above.

Comment: I think you should try creating a "main class", which has two properties `Class1` and `Class2`. Then serialize the `MainClass`. Don't forget to set serializing attributes on the two child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a main class which contains both class1 and class2 will solve the problem.